# Magento: IndexController doesn't load phtml file

Tags: php, xml, magento

As mentioned in the title I can't get my IndexController to load my view.phtml within it's index (or any other) action. Hopefully someone can help tell me what I'm doing wrong/missing. Here is what I got:

*app/etc/modules/**Namespace_MyModule.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_MyModule>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Namespace_MyModule>
    </modules>
</config>
```

*app/code/local/Namespace/MyModule/etc/**config.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_MyModule>
            <version>0.3</version>
        </Namespace_MyModule>
    </modules>


    <frontend>

        <layout>
            <updates>
                <namespace_mymodule>
                    <file>mymodule.xml</file>
                </namespace_mymodule>
            </updates>
        </layout>

        <routers>
             <namespace_mymodule>
                <use>standard</use>
                  <args>
                     <module>Namespace_MyModule</module>
                     <frontName>something</frontName>
                  </args>
             </namespace_mymodule>
        </routers>

    </frontend>

</config>
```

*app/design/frontend/default/namespace/layout/**mymodule.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<layout version="0.1.0">

    <something_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="namespace_mymodule_view" template="mymodule/view.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </something_index_index>

</layout>
```

*app/code/local/Namespace/MyModule/controllers/**IndexController.php***

```
<?php

class Namespace_MyModule_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {

    public function indexAction() {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

*app/design/frontend/default/namespace/template/mymodule/**view.phtml***

```
<h1><?php echo "What ever"; ?></h1>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it fixed now.
Some may hate me for this but the problem was that my template wasn't loaded. I had to change settings in Magento admin area.

*General->Design->Themes->Templates->"Your Template" (In my case namespace)
General->Design->Themes->Layout->"Your Template" (In my case namespace)*

or simply add it to

*General->Design->Themes->Default->"Your Template" (In my case namespace)*

wich works the same way since Magento has a fallback system.

Now I'm wondering how to add custom phtml files without the need of putting them in the template folder you are currently using but thats another topic.

Thanks *Meenakshi Sundaram R* for the help and
thanks to everyone who took his time to read through all this.

Answer (score 1):

You did a mistake in layout file. You have specify the  handle like

```
frontname_controller_action
```

So try this code

```
<layout version="0.1.0">

    <something_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="namespace_mymodule_view" template="mymodule/view.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </something_index_index>

</layout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I fixed it but it still doesn't want to work. My only guess is that I placed the template file in the wrong folder, though I have no idea...
I already tried app/design/frontend/default/namespace/template... and
app/design/frontend/base/namespace/template...

Comment: @mpfmon `Zend_Debug::dump($this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles()); exit;`
Put this in your action(after `$this->renderLayout();`) and check your handle is loaded or not.

Comment: This is what it gives me:
<pre>array(5) {
  [0] =&gt; string(7) &quot;default&quot;
  [1] =&gt; string(13) &quot;STORE_default&quot;
  [2] =&gt; string(30) &quot;THEME_frontend_default_default&quot;
  [3] =&gt; string(22) &quot;namespace_mymodule_index_index&quot;
  [4] =&gt; string(19) &quot;customer_logged_out&quot;
}
</pre>

Sry but I'm very new to this stuff...

Comment: @mpfmon Refer this [link](http://blog.belvg.com/layout-xml-directives-handles-block-reference-action-remove-update.html). it may help to you